# Redirect the pages of a site with the question mark with the htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I should redirect all links similar to this:

```
http://www.sitename.com/?918pae056d2bnnxpy
```

The problem is that these links do not have a variable that can be taken with htaccess ... so I was looking for a solution that could take all these URLs and redirect them to the home of the site.
Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear what you actually mean by "these links do not have a variable that can be taken with htaccess"... That question mark in the URL denotes request arguments ("GET arguments") that can very well be considered and modified on the level of the http server, so for example inside the apache http server's rewriting module.

Here is a simple example:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.+)$
RewriteRule ^/?$ /home.php?arg=%1 [END]
```

It internally rewrites every incoming request to `/` to `/home.php` *if* there is a query string present (so a GET argument specified). The argument itself will be handed over to the script as GET argument "arg".

There are other alternatives for most cases, but you did not tell us any details about your actual situation, so we cannot be more specific here.

The above is just an example, obviously you will need to adjust it to your needs. It is only meant as an explanation, to point you into the right direction.

Comment: I'm sorry. 
What I mean to say is that I don't have a situation like this:
http://www.sitename.com/?ID=51029
but like this:
http://www.sitename.com/?918pae056d2bnnxpy

and I have many links like this to redirect to the home of the site. All this for an attack of negative seo.

In the first case I could solve by taking the id but in my case?

Comment: I answered to that in my answer, didn't I?

Comment: Sorry, but "it doesn't work" does not help. What exactly do you mean by that? What exactly did you do? What exactly does not work? The code does what it is meant to do. It hands over the argument as GET argument with name `arg` instead of a raw query string, which is what you apparently want.